# issues while Unmarshalling using JaxB

Tags: java, jaxb, annotations

I have the following XML file to unmarshall

```
<root>
  <emp>Google</emp>
  <emp>Yahoo</emp>
  <xyz>random</xyz>
</root>
```

And i have used annotations in the following way,

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class abc {

   @XmlElement(name = "emp")
   private String emp1;
   @XmlElement(name = "emp")
   private String emp2;
   @XmlElement(name = "xyz")
   private String xyz;
   // added getters and setters for these fields
}
```

My problem is while i'm trying to get

```
   obj.getEmp1(); // result is Yahoo instead of Google
   obj.getEmp2(); // result is null.
```

Kindly clarify me, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for whatever reason you cannot use MOXy, another solution would be to map the `emp` element as a list

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class abc {
   @XmlElement(name = "emp")
   private List<String> emp;
   @XmlElement(name = "xyz")
   private String xyz;
   // added getters and setters for these fields
}
```

And then use the following code to get the values:

```
obj.getEmp().get(0);
obj.getEmp().get(1);
```

But [Blaise's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17653868/383861) is more elegant

---

You could have a `String[]` field and have your current accessor methods access the `String[]`.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class abc {

    private String[] emp = new String[2];
    private String xyz;

    public String getEmp1() {
        return emp[0];
    }

    public void setEmp1(String emp1) {
        this.emp[0] = emp1;
    }

    public String getEmp2() {
        return emp[1];
    }

    public void setEmp2(String emp2) {
        this.emp[1] = emp2;
    }

    public String getXyz() {
        return xyz;
    }

    public void setXyz(String xyz) {
        this.xyz = xyz;
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 - I hope you don't mind but I made an edit to your answer that builds on introducing a `List` property`.  The update does this with a `String[]` field, but keeps the get/set methods from the question.

Answer (score 4):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

The standard JAXB (JSR-222) annotations do not support mapping 2 different properties to the same XML element.

You could use EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)'s `@XmlPath` extension for this use case.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class abc {

   @XmlPath("emp[1]/text()")
   private String emp1;
   @XmlPath("emp[2]/text()")
   private String emp2;
   @XmlElement(name = "xyz")
   private String xyz;

   // added getters and setters for these fields
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: Can we use the same stuff in Netbeans IDE or its Eclipse plugin, please clarify?

Comment: @Rajesh - EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) is a JAXB (JSR-222) compliant implementation.  To use it you just need to have it on your classpath and specify a `jaxb.properties` file in the same package as your domain model specifying it as the provider:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: thanks a lot for your answers, any google search about jaxb annotation ends with your blog. Thanks again. @BlaiseDoughan

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```
<root>
  <emp1>Google</emp1>
  <emp2>Yahoo</emp2>
  <xyz>random</xyz>
</root>

@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class abc {

   @XmlElement(name = "emp1")
   private String emp1;
   @XmlElement(name = "emp2")
   private String emp2;
   @XmlElement(name = "xyz")
   private String xyz;
}
```